# Adding Active Directory to a web site

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been working on a site (for my company) to allow selected data center users to remotely access a scheduling calendar and some pages offering information on the various servers they are coming to the site to access--on a separate site.  Initially, I was under the impression that I'd be creating a database and registration page to add, authorize or track end users. My initial project coding has been a combination of HTML, PHP, CSS, and MySQL and Apache for the database side.  Now I've been told that we will be using AD, tied into our company's official Active Directory, so that users can use the same IDs and passwords that they've already had approved by our company.

My question is (hopefully) simple.  Is there a certain web programming language that I should use in creating the pages that works better with Active Directory than others?

Comment: You can find all of the LDAP functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

Comment: AD = Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with PHP, you should be able to achieve the above no problem!
The beauty of PHP is that someone somewhere along the line had the same problem as you so chances are, there's an established solution already.

adLdap seems to be a good solution, a library that already does most of the hard work for you and all you'd need to do would be integrate it into your script!

See: http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_user_functions

Hopefully this can make it a little easier for you so you can concentrate on the other things like the actual functionality of the website itself.